# Jquery ajax post request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, pyramid

I have a simple form submission with ajax, but it keeps giving me an error.  All the error says is "error". No code, no description. No nothing, when I alert it when it fails.

Javascript with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".post-input").submit(function(){
            var postcontent = $(".post-form").val();

            if (postcontent == ""){
                return false;
            }

            $(".post-form").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            $.ajax({
                url: '/post',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {"post-form": postcontent},
                dataType: json,
                success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert("Yay!");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<form class="post-input" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <textarea class="post-form" name="post-form" rows="1" cols="10" onFocus="this.value='';return false;">What are you thinking about...</textarea>
                <p><input class="post-submit" type="submit" name = "post.submitted" value="Post"></p>
            </form>
```

and if there are no problems there, then the server-side (pyramid):

```
def post(request):
    session = Session()
    user = authenticated_userid(request)
    postContent = request.POST['post-form']
    if not postContent == '':
        session.add(Activity(user.user_id, 0, postContent, None, None))
        return {}
    return HTTPNotFound()
```

UPDATE:
After some more debugging with firebug, I discovered that the post request body contains only post.submitted=Post, instead of the intended result of {"post-form": postcontent}.

Comment: Is it a javascript error (client), server error or python error?

Comment: @Hamish through my debugging, I'm assuming it's a client error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation, you must declare the data type:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Also, looking at your server-side code, you don't actually want to post JSON formatted data. This `{"post-form":postcontent}` is JSON formatted data. What you actually want to do is send TEXT or HTML. Seeming as it's form data, I would guess at TEXT.

**Try this:**

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/post',
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'post-form='+postcontent,
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     alert("Yay!");
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: sadly, this didn't work, but after some more debugging with firebug, I discovered that the post body is actually post. submitted = Post, instead of the intended post-form = postcontent.

Comment: Do you actually want to post JSON or just regular form data?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid there is still an error. Something I just noticed, the page is still reloading, so does that mean its not really doing an ajax request? I thought a page wasn't supposed to reload if it's only an ajax request.

Comment: @Wiz: I'm no expert but I think because you have FORM ACTION="" METHOD="POST" you are submitting the form back to the current page. Try removing these from the form element.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid the alert message that is returned from the ajax call is just "error". There are no javascript errors in the console. It passes through jslint fine. The only thing I have noticed is that the request body is not right, and that the post request is not sent to the right url, as it is just sent to the url the page is at. i.e. the post is sent to www.example.com, instead of www.example.com/post

Comment: @Wiz: You can actually do away with the whole FORM. Leave the textarea and button and change $(".post-input").submit( to $(".post-submit").click(function(){

Comment: @Wiz: Only other things I can think of are using ***CACHE:FALSE*** in the AJAX caller, make sure there are no bugs on your server-side as that will throw an error (but should be a detailed error, not 'error') and also try adding the full URL to the page you are calling.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid ok I've determined that its server side, and I threw away the whole form thing as you said. Now I just have to solve the server side, but thanks for fixing the client!

Comment: You can try changing the submit button to a regular button. It does look as if you are submitting the form **AND** submitting an AJAX call

Comment: yea that is what I have changed it to.

Comment: @Wiz: Glad I could assist. Good luck with your project.

Comment: according to the api documentation, datatype isn't even for when you are sending the data. Datatype specified what kind of data you are expecting back FROM THE SERVER. So this would not have worked to begin with

Answer (score 3):

Since you are posting `JSON`-data you have to declare the dataType "JSON":

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/post',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {"post-form": postcontent},
  success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("Yay!");
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: Missed ```});``` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the data that you are passing is not properly written.

Try to change this:

```
data: {"post-form": postcontent},
```

To this:

```
data: 'post-form='+ $('.post-form').val(),
```